# FB.ui feed dialog doesnt allow me to use an https picture?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm posting using

```
FB.ui(
           {
             method: 'feed',
             name: 'The name',
             link: 'http://www.google.com',
             picture: 'https://www.mydomain.com/mypic.jpg',
             caption: 'The caption',
             description: 'The description',
             message: ''
           }
         );
```

But the picture doesnt show! I'm sure the jpeg file exists, the file is accessible via the browser and if I move the picture to a non https location it works, but I need it to be under https due to the new facebook app policies. any clues?

Answer (score 2):

this is apparently a known (but as of yet, unresolved) bug:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292265640815869

The only workaround I've found to date is to re-host the image on a non-SSL enabled site (or depending on your site's configuration, link to the image without the HTTPS)

**EDIT:**  I was just notified by facebook that the bug has now been resolved! (30May2012)

Comment: Hi,i am not able to serve picture over https for share click.Any hint please,when i type url in browser then it works , but why not through api i am not able to undertand.